# Need help reading Unity 2022.2.4f1 Crash Log (Graphics problem?)

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, crash

I've been getting this crash in Unity 2022.2.4f1, I've asked around and some people are saying it's too ambiguous to discern, or that it may be an issue with inputs or particles, but I can't seem to figure it out right now. Any help to guide me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
Obtained 15 stack frames
0x00007ff6a0fbaa02 (Unity) GeometryJobTasks::ScheduleSharedGeometryJobs
0x00007ff6a0fbab81 (Unity) GfxDevice::ScheduleSharedGeometryJobsInternal
0x00007ff6a129abf1 (Unity) GfxDeviceClient::ScheduleSharedGeometryJobsInternal
0x00007ff6a2a3e3e4 (Unity) ParticleSystemGeometryJob::ScheduleJobs
0x00007ff6a0ac97d4 (Unity) DispatchGeometryJobs
0x00007ff6a0aa391e (Unity) Camera::CustomRender
0x00007ff6a0ab44d8 (Unity) RenderManager::RenderOffscreenCameras
0x00007ff6a1cbab80 (Unity) PlayerLoopController::InternalUpdateScene
0x00007ff6a1cc762d (Unity) PlayerLoopController::UpdateSceneIfNeededFromMainLoop
0x00007ff6a1cc5a21 (Unity) Application::TickTimer
0x00007ff6a214ee7a (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff6a2153c20 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff6a351db5e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffd6b8126bd (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffd6c16dfb8 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart (edited)
```

The editor is randomly crashing when testing an android app with Unity 2022.2.4f1, having difficulty following the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem related to this particular version of Unity? At what specific point does Unity crash? You may want to remove or disable the particles/inputs from the scene and see if the problem persists. You can also try updating Unity to version 2022.2.6f1, or switch to the LTS version, which is usually more stable.

Comment: put the log message that would be helpful